# Simple Atom-style jump-to-file

Tags: helm, files

I'm upgrading Emacs and moving from macOS to Windows after quite a few years getting by with a very old setup (eg, custom scripts for Anything). I've installed Helm. I'm interested in a simple way to:

- Specify a "project" directory without writing anything to disk or requiring any sort of
  project file to be in place already (unlike Projectile, as far as I
  can tell)
- See a list of fuzzy-matched candidates for files to jump to within that project, at any level
- Jump from the list to a selected file

In other words, I would like to recreate the experience of loading up an arbitrary directory in Atom and jumping to any file within that directory. Helm seems like a natural candidate for this, but does not seem to come with the desired functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by specifying a project? Set a variable to a directory and use that value as initial directory for a fuzzy file search? Following could do what you want `helm-find`, `helm-locate`. There are frontends for fzf: Look for counsel-fzf (which lets you set the initial directory) which comes with counsel.el, fzf.el or there is helm-fzf. And there is also counsel-file-jump.